# How to use the Computed Value to calculate another

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql

I have a query as shown below

```
Select 
  cost,
  (service_charge*(cost-Discount)) as service_charge,
  (service_tax*(cost-Discount+(service_charge*(cost-Discount)))) as service_tax
From VENDOR_ITEMS
WHERE vendor_items_id = 264
```

My question is that the value i get as `service_charge` can i use that in the calculation of `service_tax` ??

Please let me know if this is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a computed value to calculate another, but you can use [variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html):

```
SELECT
  cost,
  @sc := (service_charge*(cost-Discount)) as service_charge,
  (service_tax*(cost-Discount+( @sc ))) as service_tax
FROM
  VENDOR_ITEMS
WHERE
  vendor_items_id = 264
```

Comment: Can i initialize sc  to zero ?? (The value of service_charge)

Comment: @PreethiJain of course you can `SELECT @sc := 0 AS service_charge`, but there's no need to initialize `@sc` to zero, it will be calculated for every row. You just have to make sure that you will use it after it has been set.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat the expression

```
Select cost ,
 (service_charge*(cost-Discount)) as service_charge ,
 (service_tax*(cost-Discount+((service_charge*(cost-Discount))*(cost-Discount)))) as service_tax 
From VENDOR_ITEMS WHERE vendor_items_id = 264
```